# List of values for last attribute in Weka

Tags: weka

I am very new to Weka and data analysis. I am trying to analyze a dataset where the "result" attribute is an array. For example, the weather dataset. Right now it is just a "play or not play" answer. I would like it to be a list of activities. Maybe something like this:

```
@relation weather.symbolic
 
@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature {hot, mild, cool}
@attribute humidity {high, normal}
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute activities
 
@data
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,['swimming','golfing','sun tan','nap']
sunny,hot,high,TRUE,['swimming','golfing','fly kite','nap']
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,['swimming','golfing','nap']
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,['swimming','running','video games','nap']
rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,['video games','nap']
rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,['video games','nap']
overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,['running','golfing','video games','nap']
sunny,mild,high,FALSE,['swimming','running','video games']
sunny,cool,normal,FALSE,['swimming','running','video games']
rainy,mild,normal,FALSE,['video games','running','video games']
sunny,mild,normal,TRUE,['swimming','golfing','running','video games','fly kite']
overcast,mild,high,TRUE,['swimming','running','video games','fly kite']
overcast,hot,normal,FALSE,['swimming','running','video games']
rainy,mild,high,TRUE,['running','video games','nap']
```

I don't know if this is possible or the right way of looking at this problem. Any advice appreciated.

I have only tried a few way to indicate an array, brackets, etc.. I am using Weka Explorer.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve sounds more like multi-label learning, which Weka doesn't support. You can use [Meka](https://github.com/waikato/meka) instead.